# Receive in activity a value from intent and create a new SharedPreference

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have an activity which receives an intent with a putExtra from other activity.
And I want to create a SharedPreference each time the activity receives the putExtra value, in this case a String so I can show all the Strings stored and show in a TextView without loosing the previous String shown.

```
    tvTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    if (extras != null) {
        newNote = extras.getString("Note");

        Button noteButton = new Button(this);
        noteButton.setText(newNote);
        linearLayout.addView(noteButton);

        // and get whatever type user account id is
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",getApplication().MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("newNote", note);
        editor.commit();
        String note = prefs.getString("newNote", "Welcome");
        tvDiario.setText(note);
```

This is my code but it only saves the last string I want to show a string and then when I get a different String from intent show it but keep showing the previous, as a story. I need to edit the SharedPreference with different values each time the activity receive the putExtra data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you fully understand SharedPreferences; it's a key-value data storage. By calling:

```
editor.putString("newNote", note);
```

you always override your saved value under the `newNote` key by new value `note`. `editor.putString` does not append your new data to your stored data, it rewrites the data.

The solution: you need to get your stored data first, append new data to those stored data, and store the updated data. Try:

```
newNote = extras.getString("Note");
...
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias", getApplication().MODE_PRIVATE);
        String storedNotes = prefs.getString("notes", "");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("notes", storedNotes + newNote + "\n");
        editor.commit();
        String notes = prefs.getString("notes", "");
        tvDiario.setText(notes);
```

I exchanged your `newNote` key by `notes` to better describe what is actually stored. I also recommend to read on documentation of `Editor.putString` and `SharedPreferences.getString`, I feel like you don't have a clear idea of the interface yet.